# How to invoke DLS Step in overriding Global Library Function

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Through experimentation I have determined that I can mask the built-in pipeline steps such as `build` by defining a global function of the same name in shared library.

Example:

```
(root)
 +- vars
    +- build.groovy
```

where build.groovy is:

```
def call(Map args) {
    echo "BUILD: ${args}"
}
```

If I load this library, then none of my calls to build actually do anything. They just echo that build was called and with what args.  This is very useful for testing out pipeline scripts to ensure the script logic itself is correct while avoiding actually doing long running tasks.

But testing is only one use of this. What I really want to do is decorate `build`,  `node`, `stage` and a few other steps to capture usage metrics.  For example to record for every node that is ever allocated, what time of day it was allocated, and how long it was allocated for.  This could be really useful for capacity analysis and planning.

Another application would be to enforce certain policies, such that nodes always be allocated by label and never by explicit node name.

To make any of this work though, the `node.groovy` decorator needs some way to invoke the real `node` step that it is masking.  *Any ideas how to do this?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out this evening.  All the dsl steps are available as members of the `steps` variable. Which allows me to write something like:

```
@Library('pipeline-utils')
import mycompany.analytics.AnalyticsClient
import mycompany.analytics.Utils

node('linux') { sh 'echo test' }

def node(String label, Closure nodeAction) {
    def executionTime
    def actualNode
    def allocationTime = Utils.startMeasureDuration()

    steps.node(label){
        allocationTime.stop()
        actualNode = env.NODE_NAME
        executionTime = Utils.measureDuration(nodeAction)
    }

    def fact = [
        type: 'node_usage', 
        job_name: currentBuild.getProjectName(),
        node_label: label,
        node_name: actualNode,
        ts: allocationTime.startTS,
        time_in_queue: allocationTime.durationMillis,
        execution_time: executionTime.durationMillis
    ]
    AnalyticsClient.recordFact(fact)

    if(!executionTime.success) throw executionTime.exception
}
```

Comment: Just had the same issue, saved my life!

Comment: Glad it helped.